# objective-c modalViewController too quick

Tags: objective-c, syntax, foreach, language-features

I am having an issue dismissing a modal view controller on a certain edge case. I display the modal view when I am retrieving a PDF to display in a UIWebView. When the file I am retrieving is very small the modal view will try to dismiss too soon. I present the modal view in the view controller that contains the UIWebView. I dismiss it in the UIWebView's didFinishLoad delegate method.

I am fine with not animating the initial presentation of the modal view... but is that any more safe than what I was doing? does this still have potential to fail, and if so how would you change it? I have been looking through the docs and nothing I have read so far adresses this situation.

```
//
// This will download the file if not @ specific path, otherwise use local file.
// _myFileManager is a helper class and _myFileRecord is the backing data model
//
-(id)initWithNib... fileRecord:(MYFileRecord *)_myFileRecord
{
    [_myFileManager cacheFileAsync:_myFileRecord delegate:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // doesn't seem to work, NO for animated does seem to work
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:_splashController 
                                                 animated:YES];        
    _splashController.messageLabel.text = @"Retrieving File...";
}

- (void)recordSaved:(MyFileRecord *)myFileRecord fileName:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    _splashController.messageLabel.text = @"Opening File...";
}

//
// This fails when a small file is already cached to disk and the time
// for the webView to finishLoad is faster than the splashView can present itself
//
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the `viewDidAppear` in your SplashController, to catch when the view has finished animating, and set a flag. Then you can control if the SplashController's view has finished loading using this flag, and wait for it if it is not finished yet?

E.g.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear {
  if (shouldDismiss) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
  readyToDismiss = YES;
}
```

And in your main VC:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView*)webViewv
{
  if (_splashController.readyToDismiss) {
    [_splashController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  } else {
    _splashController.shouldDismiss = YES; // will dismiss in viewDidAppear
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, however I only use one bool readyToDismiss and replace shouldDismiss with it. do you see anything wrong with that?

Comment: No pb, this should be OK too (and also more simple)! I used two BOOLs for the sake of readability in my answer, but you're right, using only one BOOL for both cases (animation finished before webview, or the opposite) is fine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try testing to see if the splashView has finished and use `performSelector:afterDelay:` to check back later.

My idea is to create a method like this

```
-(void)dismissWhenReady {
    if ( splashView is finished) {
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else 
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismissWhenReady) afterDelay:1.0];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is essentially polling, which I want to avoid +1 because it probably is a working solution though.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` fires too early (before it is displayed), you will want to use `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` to present your modal view instead along with a flag to know if it is the first load. If it still does not display long enough add a delay for the desired amount of time.